# How to make each Window assigned to a particular Desktop in Mac spaces

Tags: macos, desktop, workspace

Whenever i put the window in their desktop, after a while i notice the location of window changed by itself.

Any way to make it stay assign to a single desktop forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Mission Control and disable ‘Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use’.

[image]